# Select, Checkbox, and Radio button elements in Sinatra with Datamapper

Tags: ruby, sinatra, haml

Using Datamapper with Sinatra, it's really easy to save text properties:

```
DataMapper::setup(:default, "sqlite3://#{Dir.pwd}/tailor.db")  
class Person  
  include DataMapper::Resource  
  property :id, Serial  
  property :name, String, :required => true
  property :height, String, :required => false
end  
DataMapper.finalize.auto_upgrade!

...

put '/:id/edit' do
  p = Person.get params[:id]
  p.name = params[:name]
  p.height = params[:height]
  p.save
end
```

And the view:

```
%form
  %input{:type => 'text', :name => 'name'}
  %input{:type => 'text', :name => 'height'}
  %input{:type => 'submit', :value => 'Save'}
```

With `:type => 'text'` it is a breeze. However, I'm running into trouble trying to set a boolean (`property :test, Boolean, :required => false`) with a checkbox. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3176367/how-do-i-work-with-checkboxes-with-datamapper-and-sinatra) is similar, but doesn't address how to do a simple boolean.

In addition, what is the easiest way to set up values that don't accept any string, but rather just a set of predefined options—either as a select that allows one choice, or a set of radio buttons that allows several?

**EDIT:**

I figured out checkboxes:

```
p.bool = !params[:bool].nil?
```

and in the view:

```
  %input{:type => 'checkbox', :name => 'bool', :value => "#{@bool}", :checked => @p.bool}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you submit a form with a `checkbox`, if you don’t specify the `value` form it the default is the string `on`. Additionally, if the checkbox isn’t selected it doesn’t get submitted at all. So the result is that in your handler, `params[:test]` (assuming the `checkbox` is named `test`) is either `nil` if it was unchecked, or the string `on` if it was.

A boolean property in Datamapper is expecting to be assigned either a Boolean (`true` or `false`), or one of a [small set of values that it will implicitly convert](https://github.com/datamapper/dm-core/blob/v1.2.0/lib/dm-core/property/boolean.rb#L8-9). `on` and `nil` are not among those values, so when you try to assign the value to Datamapper it will fail validation and not save:

```ruby
...
p.test = 'on'
if !p.save
  p p.errors[:test]
end
```

produces:

```
["Test must be of type TrueClass"]
```

One way to fix this is to check in your handler and explicitly convert the value to a boolean when assigning to the property:

```ruby
p.test = params[:test] == 'on' ? true : false
```

Another technique is to set the `value` in the HTML checkbox to one of the values that Datamapper will convert, so you can pass it directly. You can have multiple controls with the same name in a form, and they will be submitted in the order they appear in the page. Sinatra will only use the last one when creating the `params` hash, so if you add a `hidden` input with the same name as the checkbox *before* the checkbox, then if it is not checked the value will be that of the hidden input. If it is checked, its value will override that of the hidden input.

```haml
%input{:type => 'hidden', :name => 'foo', :value => 'f'}
%input{:type => 'checkbox', :name => 'foo', :value => 't'}
```

Now `params[:test]` will be either `'f'` or `'t'`,, both of which Datamapper will convert for you, so you can simply do

```ruby
p.test = params[:test]
```